# How do I exact match all the words in a string includes those ends with '!,?.'"' but do not match those with any other punctuation using regex?

Tags: python, regex, regex-group, regex-negation

For example, if the pattern I want to search for is `apple`

The string I want to search into is
`apple apple@323 apple.. apple??...!! apple??%% Ilovesapple`

Expected matches:

```
apple 
apple.. 
apple??...!!
```

I want to match all the exact words, the only exception is that the word ends with the punctuation in
`!,?.'"`

Comment: You just discovered the need of escape sequences. Typically, you would escape something with a leading backwards slash \

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Is this what you want ?

```
\bapple[!,?.'\"]*(?=\s+|$)
```

[Regex Demo](https://regex101.com/r/xv21qJ/1)

[image]

### Details:

- `\b`  word boundary for 'apple'
- `apple`  the pattern you want to search
- `[!,?.'\"]*`  zero or more occurrences of the special character(s) at the end that you want to match
- `(?=\s+|$)` Positive Lookahead to ensure the matching word is followed by white space or end of line.

### Another version

Another possibility is this if you don't allow any non-space characters before 'apple':

```
(?:\s+|^)(apple[!,?.'\"]*)(?=\s+|$)
```

[Regex Demo](https://regex101.com/r/Nsj8yj/1)   Note that `@apple?` is not matched because it starts with `@`

Refer to `Group 1` for the matches

[image]

### Details:

- `(?:\s+|^)`  non-capturing group for white space(s) or beginning of line before 'apple'
- `(`    start of capturing group (captured into Group 1)

  - `apple`  the pattern you want to search
  - `[!,?.'\"]*`  zero or more occurrences of the special character(s) at the end that you want to match
- `)`    end of capturing group (captured into Group 1)
- `(?=\s+|$)` Positive Lookahead to ensure the matching word is followed by white space or end of line.

Comment: Thank you, this is exactly what I want!